# Set PHP to always redirect on error 500s

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling

On my website I would like it to redirect all error 500 errors to /500.html. As of current some of the page displays with `GET 
http://localhost/ [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]` in the Developer Tools. I have tried implementing this by editing `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. The file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I have also tried editing `apache2.conf` and `.htaccess` but I get the same result.

**P.S: I have tried restarting Apache every time!**

Comment: Have you tried something like `ErrorDocument 500 http://google.com` to check if the `ErrorDocument` works? Stock Response: have you checked the Apache error.log? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to intercept 500 errors from PHP in apache using `mod_php` with `SetHandler` (A very common way), then the answer is that you can't. To the best of my knowledge it's not a supported feature.

However there are ways such as using PHP via it's FastCGI interface ([PHP-FPM](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)) and the Apache [proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_proxy.html) module to achieve what you require.

First, you may need to ensure that `mod_proxy` and `proxy_fcgi_module` are installed on your server and enabled in the Apache config like so:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

Also ensure that PHP-FPM is installed and running as a service, the default port it uses is 9000.

Then replace your apache PHP configuration (possibly in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf) with the following.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
```

This will mean that you are now using the Apache Proxy module to send traffic to PHP. It is possible to instruct Apache to intercept error responses from the proxy module and use custom error handlers with the following in your `VirtualHost` section.

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution did not work, however I do now get a fullscreen 500 error message from my web browser. I have checked my steps and I get no errors in my Apache error log. (Although of coarse I get an error 500 because I'm testing!)

Comment: To clarify - the 500 error is on purpose for testing and valid PHP content works normally? The issue with the solution is that you still do not get a custom 500 error page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. +Steve E.

Comment: Could you try `ErrorDocument 500 "Custom Error"` to eliminate any local path issues as the cause. And check the logs when Apache starts for configuration warnings. The access log for the request should show the response code is `500` and not anything else.

Comment: After realising it wasn't the `php.ini` I need to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` I get a error 503 on every PHP page and I found this error in the Apache error log `[Wed Apr 13 16:50:27.801751 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 3126] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed [Wed Apr 13 16:50:27.801788 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3126] [client ::1:48025] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1` +Steve E.

Comment: That suggests Apache is working, but PHP-FPM isn't. Is the PHP-FPM service running? If it is then you should be able to `telnet 127.0.0.1 9000` and get a response. PHP-FPM logs are possibly in /var/log/php-fpm/*log

Comment: +Steve E. It would seem as if PHP5-FPM is running as in the FPM logs it seems to have started successfully but I still get the error 503 on every page I visit along with the same error in the logs.

Comment: Seems like you are close. There are many ways to check PHP-FPM is listening on port 9000. `telnet 127.0.0.1 9000` should get a connection. `curl 127.0.0.1:9000` should return Failure receiving data. `netstat -tulpn | grep 9000` should list php-fpm. What is the `listen` value in ` /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` ?

Comment: The telnet curl and netstat requests don't return the desired result. The listen value is `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. +Steve E.

Comment: No that file DOES exist... +Steve E.

Comment: That's v. helpful. Change the listen value to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and it will work.

Comment: What's the error in the apache logs now? Did you restart PHP-FPM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109197/discussion-between-steve-e-and-im-on-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

Custom error documents are configured using the `ErrorDocument` directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory context. It may be used in `.htaccess` files if `AllowOverride` is set to `FileInfo`.

```
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/not_found.html 
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
```

The syntax of the ErrorDocument directive is:

```
ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>
```

where the action will be treated as:

1. A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").
2. An external URL to redirect to (if the action is a valid URL).
3. Text to be displayed (if none of the above). The text must be wrapped in
   quotes (") if it consists of more than one word. When redirecting to
   a local URL, additional environment variables are set so that the
   response can be further customized. They are not sent to external
   URLs.

[Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

> Keep in mind that the Apache looks for the 404 page located within the
>   site's server root. Meaning that if you place the new error page in a
>   deeper subdirectory, you need to include that in the line.

Comment: @I'monstackexchange you still get standard 500 error page from /500.html ?

Comment: Yes. +Tomasz Turkowski

Comment: @I'monstackexchange did you tried to overwrite current content of /500.html ?

Comment: +Tomasz Turkowski No, I'm trying to make it redirect on an error 500!

Answer (score 0):

I found this code here:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ErrorDocument 500 /custom_500.html
</VirtualHost>
```

then the custom pages go here: /var/www/html
and the file you need to edit is this or similar:

```
   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

also enable these 2 mods, and then check for syntax errors and restart apache

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo service apache2 restart
```

tell me if this works for your server, because on my server after some tries, it worked

Comment: sorry if i made you waste some time, i hope someone other will help you solving this problem